# Disable Encryption without wiping data in Custom Rom

Tags: security, custom-roms, encryption

Does it possible to disable encryption in **Android10+** without wiping data partition to access personal data?
(unlocked bootloader)

In other words, Can I trust custom roms to **protect** my data?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. Formatting userdata partition to remove encryption is mandatory.